# Sharding with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am newbie to MongoDB Sharding. I have created `mongos` and `config server` and one shard on `xyz.com`, and second shard on `xyzshard.com` server:

- `mongos` on `xyz.com:27019`
- `config server` on `xyz.com:27018`
- 1st shard on `xyz.com:27017`
- 2nd shard on `xyzshard.com:27017`

My database is `test` and collection is `test_collection`. I have enabled sharding on `test.test_collection`.

I have indexed `_id` field using `"hash"`

```
db.test_collection.ensureIndex( { _id : "hashed" } )
```

I run the following command:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 500; i++) 
    db.test_collection.insert( { x : i } )
```

I get the output below:

```
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

But when I run find query on both shards like this:

```
db.test_collection.find()
```

I get all documents on each shard.

Is it the right way or I am going wrong anywhere?

**Output for sh.status() on xyz.com is**

```
sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("55b8d3e9a8742d49164820b6")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "localhost:27017" }
  balancer:
    Currently enabled:  yes
    Currently running:  no
    Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
    Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
        No recent migrations
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
        test.test_collection
            shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
            chunks:
                shard0000   2
            { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong(0) } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 1) 
            { "_id" : NumberLong(0) } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 2) 
    {  "_id" : "test_db",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
    {  "_id" : "db",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
```

**Output for sh.status() on xyzshard.com**

```
sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("55b8d3e9a8742d49164820b6")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "localhost:27017" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
        test.test_collection
            shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
            chunks:
                shard0000   2
            { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong(0) } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 1) 
            { "_id" : NumberLong(0) } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 2) 
    {  "_id" : "test_db",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
    {  "_id" : "db",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
```

Comment: You mean you get 500 documents as a result of the `find` query on **both** shards? Or in summary, e.g. 200 on `xyz.com`, 300 on `xyzshard.com`?

Comment: yes...i am getting 500 documents on both shards each

Comment: Can you try sh.status: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.status/

Comment: What's the output you get? Can you paste it?

Comment: hi lalit i had add the output in the question

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to your mongos server and insert data on it.You could insert 50000 records for testing purpose. 
And after that run sh.status().

You would finally see the distribution.
Remember your config server should be  running and all the shard servers are connected to the mongos server.